# Is android.os.Build.MODEL stable?

Tags: android

Does anyone know if Build.Model is stable? Can we rely on it not changing between updates from the manufacturer?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL

Thanks

Comment: Users on rooted devices could change the value since it is read from a system property. And a firmware update can change everything, meaning nothing in Android is guaranteed to be firmware update stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we rely on it not changing between updates from the manufacturer?

Yes, simply because it is a `static final` value, and therefore cannot change except by "updates from the manufacturer" to change the class definition.